# Why doesn't ToString work in ReplaceAll?

Tags: replacement, string-manipulation

I'm trying to use `ReplaceAll` in a subscript. However, it doesn't seem to work as expected if I want to use the output the subscript in a `ToString`. See below:

```
Subscript[A, 1] /. Subscript[A, x_] -> x
Subscript[A, 1] /. Subscript[A, x_] -> ToString[x]
Subscript[A, 1] /. Subscript[A, x_] -> f[x]
```

> ```
> 1
> x
> f[1]
> ```

The first and third cases are resulting in the expected output, but `ToString` seems to have some special attribute that doesn't allow the replacement rule to process in the second case. What is causing this behaviour?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing special about `ToString`.  In this kind of replacement you need to use `RuleDelayed`, `:>`.

```
Subscript[A, 1] /. Subscript[A, x_] :> ToString[x]
```

Try applying `Trace` to both forms of the expression and compare the order things are evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

```
Subscript[A, 1] /. Subscript[A, x_] -> x // ToString
```